# Multiple scraping: problem in the code. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to use Selenium scraping on multiple elements (for personal study reasons, so for personal didactic reasons, no-profit). A multiple scrape with multiple scraped elements that create a row that will fit into the database. I have never created a multiple scraping so far, but I have always scraped single elements. So there is some problem in the code.

I would like to create this row for each round (round 1, round 2, etc.) of the championship: **Round, Date, Team_Home, Team_Away, Result_Home, Result_Away**. In detail, just for information and to give you a better idea, there will be 8 rows for each championship round. The total turns are 26. I'm not getting any errors, but the output is just >>>. I only receive this >>>, with no text or errors. The purpose of the request and the code is only for personal study reasons, so for personal didactic reasons, no profit. This question and this code is not for commercial or profit-making purposes.

I would like to get, for example, this:

```
#SWEDEN ALLSVENKAN
#Round, Date, Team_Home, Team_Away, Result_Home, Result_Away

Round 1, 11/31/2021 20:45, AIK Stockholm, Malmo, 2, 1
Round 1, 11/31/2021 20:45, Elfsborg, Gothenburg, 2, 3
...and the rest of the other matches of the 1st round

Round 2, 06/12/2021 20:45, Gothenburg, AIK Stockholm, 0, 1
Round 2, 06/12/2021 20:45, Malmo, Elfsborg, 1, 1
...and the rest of the other matches of the 2st round

Round 3, etc.
```

Python code for scraping:

```
Values_Allsvenskan = []

#SCRAPING
driver.get("link")
driver.implicitly_wait(12)
driver.minimize_window()

for Allsvenskan in multiple_scraping:

    try:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[id='event__more event__more--static']"))).click()
    except:
        pass

    multiple_scraping = round, date, team_home, team_away, score_home, score_away

    #row/record
    round = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href^='/squadra'][class^='event__round event__round--static']")
    date = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href^='/squadra'][class^='event__time']")
    team_home = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href^='/squadra'][class^='event__participant event__participant--home']")            
    team_away = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href^='/squadra'][class^='event__participant event__participant--away']")
    score_home = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href^='/squadra'][class^='event__score event__score--home']")
    score_away = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href^='/squadra'][class^='event__score event__score--away']")   


    Allsvenskan_text = round.text, date.text, team_home.text, team_away.text, score_home.text, score_away.text
    Values_Allsvenskan.append(tuple([Allsvenskan_text]))
    print(Allsvenskan_text)
driver.close


    #INSERT IN DATABASE
    con = sqlite3.connect('/database.db')
    cursor = con.cursor()
    sqlite_insert_query_Allsvenskan = 'INSERT INTO All_Score (round, date, team_home, team_away, score_home, score_away) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);'
    cursor.executemany(sqlite_insert_query_Allsvenskan, Values_Allsvenskan)
    con.commit()
```

Based on my python code, can you show me how I can fix and fix the code? Thanks

**UPDATE FOR INSERT IN DATABASE**

```
#INSERT IN DATABASE
con = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
cursor = con.cursor()
sqlite_insert_query_Allsvenskan = 'INSERT INTO All_Score(current_round, date, team_home, team_away, score_home, score_away) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);'
cursor.executemany(sqlite_insert_query_Allsvenskan, results = [])
con.commit()
```

**FINAL UPDATE FOR LOGIC CODE, AFTER THE FINAL ANSWER: I ADD ONLY THE COMMENT TO EXPLAIN THE STEPS.**
If I miss a comment or need to add something, go ahead. I want to make sure I understand the logic of the code

```
#I search for rows with event__round or event__match
all_rows = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class^='event__round'],div[class^='event__match']")

#Initializing an empty list
results = []

#Value default of the round before the for loop
current_round = '?'

#Check which classes of event__round and event__match have lines. It is used to recognize the row with Round?????
for row in all_rows:
     classes = row.get_attribute ('class')

## If round number and match both have rows, then I use find_element to get the rest of the other data to scrape
    if.........
    else.....
```

Comment: first scrape full rows and next use `for`-loop it to scrape values from every row separatelly - using `row.find_elements` instead of `driver.find_elements` - and this way you can create row with all values. Eventually you can use `zip(...)` to create rows but if some row will have empty place then it may put value from next row and it will gives wrong rows.

Comment: you forgot `()` in `driver.close()`

Comment: @furas  Thanks, I thought no one answered. Maybe I understand, but I'm not sure. Could you show me your suggestion applied to my code please? How would you write my code? Can you show me an answer? Obviously I will vote for it and set the question resolved. I'm starting out with Python, sorry. Ah, do you think I could have also written "multiple_scraping" wrong? Thanks

Comment: now I try to create working code - at this moment I found that page doesn't have `a[href^='/squadra']` - If I remove it then it start working but I still didn't check if it gives all needed data.

Comment: next problem is that `Round 1` is as header for other rows so it would need much more complex core.

Comment: @furas  I thank you. You are really kind. I really appreciate your help. I just didn't know how to fix. Thanks. Ah yes, a [href ^ = '/ team'] is my mistake, because I did several copy and paste to create those lines and used the same line. My forgetfulness and distraction. I didn't understand the problem of Round 1. Could you help me anyway please? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `find_elements` to get lists with all `rounds`, all `date`, all `team_home`, all `team_away`, etc. so you have values in separated list and you should use `zip()` to group values in lists like [`single round`, `single date`, `single team_home`, ...]`

```
results = []

for row in zip(date, team_home, team_away, score_home, score_away):
    row = [item.text for item in row]
    print(row)
    results.append(row)
```

I skiped `round` because it makes more problems it will need totally differnt code.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.diretta.it/calcio/svezia/allsvenskan/risultati/")
driver.implicitly_wait(12)
#driver.minimize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[id='event__more event__more--static']"))).click()
except Exception as ex:
    print('EX:', ex)

round = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class^='event__round event__round--static']")
date = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class^='event__time']") #data e ora è tutto un pezzo su diretta.it
team_home = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class^='event__participant event__participant--home']")            
team_away = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class^='event__participant event__participant--away']")
score_home = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class^='event__score event__score--home']")
score_away = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class^='event__score event__score--away']")   

results = []

for row in zip(date, team_home, team_away, score_home, score_away):
    row = [item.text for item in row]
    print(row)
    results.append(row)
```

Result:

```
['01.11. 19:00', 'Degerfors', 'Göteborg', '0', '1']
['01.11. 19:00', 'Halmstad', 'AIK Stockholm', '1', '0']
['01.11. 19:00', 'Mjallby', 'Hammarby', '2', '0']
['31.10. 17:30', 'Örebro', 'Djurgarden', '0', '1']
['31.10. 15:00', 'Norrkoping', 'Elfsborg', '3', '2']
['30.10. 17:30', 'Hacken', 'Kalmar', '1', '4']
['30.10. 15:00', 'Sirius', 'Malmo FF', '2', '3']
['30.10. 15:00', 'Varbergs', 'Östersunds', '3', '0']
['28.10. 19:00', 'Degerfors', 'Elfsborg', '1', '2']
['28.10. 19:00', 'Göteborg', 'Djurgarden', '3', '0']
['28.10. 19:00', 'Halmstad', 'Örebro', '1', '1']
['28.10. 19:00', 'Norrkoping', 'Mjallby', '2', '2']
['27.10. 19:00', 'Kalmar', 'Varbergs', '2', '2']
['27.10. 19:00', 'Malmo FF', 'AIK Stockholm', '1', '0']
['27.10. 19:00', 'Östersunds', 'Hacken', '1', '1']
['27.10. 19:00', 'Sirius', 'Hammarby', '0', '1']
['25.10. 19:00', 'Örebro', 'Degerfors', '1', '2']
['24.10. 17:30', 'AIK Stockholm', 'Norrkoping', '1', '0']
...
```

But this method may sometimes makes problem - if some row has empty place then it will move value from next row to current row, etc. This way it can create wrong rows.

Better is to find all rows (`div` or `tr`  in `table`) and next use `for-loop` to work with every row separatelly and use `row.find_elements` instead of `driver.find_elements`. This should also resolve problem with `round` which will need to read value and later duplicate it in next rows.

I search rows with `event__round` or `event__match` and next I check what classes has row. If it has `event__round` then I get `round`.  If it has `event__match` then I use `find_element` without `s` at the end to get single `date`, single `team_home`, single `team_away`, etc (because in single row there are only single values) and use them with `current_round` to create row.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.diretta.it/calcio/svezia/allsvenskan/risultati/")
driver.implicitly_wait(12)
#driver.minimize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[id='event__more event__more--static']"))).click()
except Exception as ex:
    print('EX:', ex)

all_rows = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class^='event__round'],div[class^='event__match']")

results = []

current_round = '?'

for row in all_rows:
    classes = row.get_attribute('class')
    #print(classes)
    
    if 'event__round' in classes:
        #round = row.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class^='event__round event__round--static']")
        #current_round = row.text  # full text `Round 20`
        current_round = row.text.split(" ")[-1]  # only `20` without `Round`
    else:
        datetime = row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class^='event__time']")
        
        date, time = datetime.text.split(" ")
        date = date.rstrip('.')  # right-strip to remove `.` at the end of date
        
        team_home = row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class^='event__participant event__participant--home']")            
        team_away = row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class^='event__participant event__participant--away']")
        score_home = row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class^='event__score event__score--home']")
        score_away = row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class^='event__score event__score--away']")   

        # old version
        #row = [current_round, datetime.text, team_home.text, team_away.text, score_home.text, score_away.text]
    
        row = [current_round, date, time, team_home.text, team_away.text, score_home.text, score_away.text]
        results.append(row)
        print(row)

# --- database ---

import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
cursor = con.cursor()

query = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS All_Score;'
cursor.execute(query)

# old version - with only `date`
#query = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS All_Score(current_round, date, team_home, team_away, score_home, score_away);'
# new version - with `date` and `time`
query = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS All_Score(current_round, date, time, team_home, team_away, score_home, score_away);'
cursor.execute(query)

# old version - with only `date`
#query = 'INSERT INTO All_Score(current_round, date, team_home, team_away, score_home, score_away) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);'
# new version - with `date` and `time`
query = 'INSERT INTO All_Score(current_round, date, time, team_home, team_away, score_home, score_away) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);'
cursor.executemany(query, results)

con.commit()
```

Result:

```
['Giornata 26', '01.11. 19:00', 'Degerfors', 'Göteborg', '0', '1']
['Giornata 26', '01.11. 19:00', 'Halmstad', 'AIK Stockholm', '1', '0']
['Giornata 26', '01.11. 19:00', 'Mjallby', 'Hammarby', '2', '0']
['Giornata 26', '31.10. 17:30', 'Örebro', 'Djurgarden', '0', '1']
['Giornata 26', '31.10. 15:00', 'Norrkoping', 'Elfsborg', '3', '2']
['Giornata 26', '30.10. 17:30', 'Hacken', 'Kalmar', '1', '4']
['Giornata 26', '30.10. 15:00', 'Sirius', 'Malmo FF', '2', '3']
['Giornata 26', '30.10. 15:00', 'Varbergs', 'Östersunds', '3', '0']

['Giornata 25', '28.10. 19:00', 'Degerfors', 'Elfsborg', '1', '2']
['Giornata 25', '28.10. 19:00', 'Göteborg', 'Djurgarden', '3', '0']
['Giornata 25', '28.10. 19:00', 'Halmstad', 'Örebro', '1', '1']
# ...
```